# Full Calendar add More "LINK" for the day

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

Wanted to add "More" link for the day calendar? Can anyone help me out doing this ? Here's the code. However it is coming for the month view not for the day. Wanted same link for the day view. Thanks in advance

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        minTime: '#{@timing_slots[:start_time]}',
        maxTime: '#{@timing_slots[:end_time]}',
        slotDuration: '00:45:00',
        //themeSystem: 'bootstrap',

        height: 820,

        defaultDate: date,
        editable: false,
        selectable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
        },
        views: {
            agendaDay: {
                type: 'agenda',
                duration: {days: 1},


                // views that are more than a day will NOT do this behavior by default
                // so, we need to explicitly enable it
                groupByResource: true

                //// uncomment this line to group by day FIRST with resources underneath
                //groupByDateAndResource: true
            },
            day: {
                titleFormat: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY',




            }
        },
```

Comment: As documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover the `eventLimit` only applies to "month" and "basic" views, and also to the "all day" section of "agenda" views (regardless of whether they cover a day, a week or anything else). It shouldn't really be necessary for the main agenda view (i.e. outside the all-day section) because there's plenty of space to display events across the whole timeline of the day. It also wouldn't make much logical sense, because the events shown in the eventLimit popover window are not in a time grid anymore, yet that is the purpose of the agenda view.

Comment: Thanks ! I was going through the documentation i found that information i-e EventLimit only applies to certain view. However in my case things was little different I'm trying to implement "one day vertical view in my screen and events are just overlapping"  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-standard-demo.    Is there anyway you can suggest to implement so that the event's does not overlap regardless of how many in one hour. Thanks in advance @ADyson

Comment: There's this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap which you can set as per your preference so that the events appear side-by-side instead of partially on top of each other. Does that help?

Comment: Great works fine. But there's one issue the event's height and width ain't the same. Anyway can we change dat i tried to overwrite the styling but no luck. any idea ? Thanks in advance @ADyson

Comment: does it really matter that much? The height is of course determined by the length of time the event lasts for...so it will always vary. If you have a very long event you really aren't going to want it to be equally wide, it will obscure the rest of the calendar days. I don't think having equal height and width for each event is a sensible goal.

Comment: In my case the events time are same but the length and width are vary. anyway we can make height and width equal for all events? Thanks @ADyson

Comment: will they always be the same forever? Surely it's possible to anticipate that this fact might change eventually. Anyway, no I don't think it's easy to do this without changing the fullCalendar source code. fullCalendar sets the size of the event elements dynamically in order to fit into the correct position on the grid, which is also generated dynamically based on various settings, and the size of the screen etc. So if you set any kind of fixed value it will not work in all cases. I think it's really a very minor problem and not worth the hassle of trying to change it.

Comment: Yea it will be same almost. But now the time slots aren't aligned properly.However they not overlapping but due do not aligned properly they just floating towards right . I have "vertical resource view " https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view . So if there's many events in a hour they just floating towards right. Need a way to align i guess .

Comment: "now the time slots aren't aligned properly"...have you been messing with the CSS? If I understand correctly what you're describing (the events are floating to the right of the column?) then this isn't a problem observable with standard fullCalendar.

Comment: No i did not tried to change any CSS. Since the view is "vertical resource" only concern was if there's more than 3-4 events in one hours the event's are just floating towards right. And  Also anyway to make this "Responsive" @ADyson

Comment: fullcalendar doesn't really support responsiveness unfortunately. It's a fixed grid system. What specific kind of responsive behaviour exactly would you expect, in any case? There are many possible ways one could potentially try to build a "responsive" calendar, it's a word with a very broad and vague definition.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "float towards the right" in that case - can you provide a demo based on the codepen you linked to?

Comment: I was trying to make the height and width of the event according to the size of the content . Ex: height:max-content and same for the width. But no luck i guess i'm not able to pick right class to overwrite the changes.  Here's the class i tried to change the CSS on "fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end".  No luck  @ADyson

Comment: so actually you **are** messing with the CSS. The height of the event should obviously be according to _where it fits on the grid_. That's how you know what time it occurs! The events are overlaid in a separate table on top of the time grid table. In order for it not to get out of alignment, you have to let fullCalendar set the correct positioning. I don't understand why you are attempting to modify it, it's not logical. Messing with the width is less of an issue, unless it gets too wide, but you're clearly getting undesirable results, so remove each change until it works again.

Comment: @ADyson Responsive i meant atleast i can view my calendar on ipad screen or phone screen . Anway we can do that ?

Comment: I've already answered that, above. No current support for anything but the standard grid, which may or may not be legible on a smaller screen depending on the setup and content of the particular calendar being displayed. And any way "view on phone screen" is _far_ too vague to be a requirement. There are lots of ways the view could potentially be compressed, depending on the desired UX. It would be a complex piece of work requiring some careful thought and planning. Maybe you can write a plugin for fullCalendar to support your desired functionality :-)